# How to get the current Page Number from PDF form using PDFBOX?

Tags: java, pdfbox

How to get the current Page Number from PDF form using PDFBOX ?

Is there any way to get the particular fields page number? For example, if a text box named `First name` is present on 4 page of a PDF form is it possible to retrieve current Page number as 4?

Any insight into a possible solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am usually filling the page number information on every new page during the pdf build. This means that I know the page number of the edited page which is currently the last page.

```
private void addPageNumber(int page, PDPageContentStream content) throws Exception {
  content.beginText();
  String pageNumber = page + "";
  // TODO: move to the needed text position
  content.drawString(pageNumber);
  content.endText();
}
```

I call this method with the current number of pages as a parameter:

```
addPageNumber(_document.getNumberOfPages(), content);
```