# How to access current page number of pdf in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

How to get the current Page Number from PDF form using PDFBOX ?

Is their anyway to get the particular fields page number for eg if a text box named First name is present in 4 page of PDF form is it possible to retrieve current Page number as 4

Can any one share u r view

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read the current page number of the pdf document using pdfbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836743/how-to-read-the-current-page-number-of-the-pdf-document-using-pdfbox)

Comment: may not be actually i want to get the page number of opened page when a link is clicked

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831695/how-to-get-the-current-page-number-from-pdf-form-using-pdfbox